# C# HttpWebRequest does not work with https. The program gets stuck on the line HttpWebResponse execute

Tags: c#, json, .net, httpwebrequest

Below is the link which is https and return the JSON. but the code gets stuck on the HttpWebResponse and nothing happens. It does not go in the catch block also.

```
public static string GetWebSource(string URL)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    if (URL != "")
    {

        // used to build entire input

        try
        {

            // used on each read operation
            byte[] buf = new byte[8192];

            // prepare the web page we will be asking for
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)
                WebRequest.Create("https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY");


            request.ContentType = "application/json";
            request.Method = "GET";

            // execute the request
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)
                request.GetResponse();

            // we will read data via the response stream
            Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

            string tempString = null;
            int count = 0;

            do
            {
                // fill the buffer with data
                count = resStream.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);

                // make sure we read some data
                if (count != 0)
                {
                    // translate from bytes to ASCII text
                    tempString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buf, 0, count);

                    // continue building the string
                    sb.Append(tempString);
                }
            }
            while (count > 0); // any more data to read?

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            
        }
    }

    // print out page source
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

Comment: HTTPS is secure and uses TLS for authentication.  Error indicates the TLS is failing.  You should be using Net 4.7.2 and newer which uses the Operating System for TLS.  Adding following static method to beginning of the code sometimes solves issue : ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

Comment: @jdweng: "Error indicates the TLS is failing." Err, what error? You seem to be making a pretty big assumption here. (I've just tested your suggested change, and it makes no difference.)

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. I tried adding ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 but it is getting stuck. The json file on the location is opening fine in browser https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY, can there exist any authentication issues also ?

Comment: I *suspect* this is a server issue - it fails with Curl as well (with a permission failure), and with `HttpClient` in .NET (just hanging). I don't know exactly what's going on, but the statement in your title that "HttpWebRequest does not work with https" is an overstatement.

Comment: (I'd also note that your approach to reading the response is both longwinded and broken... it would be much simpler to just create a `StreamReader` around the response stream and call `ReadToEnd`. Currently you're assuming that each block you read ends at a UTF-8 character boundary, and that's not a good assumption. I'd also *very strongly* advise you to avoid empty catch blocks like this)

Comment: I'd also note that it's probably not a good idea to set a content type when your request doesn't provide any content...

Comment: @JonSkeet thanks for the inputs. I'll surely avoid these in future.

Comment: If it is working with browser it is not server.  This is TLS with NET/Core issue.  What version of Net are you using?  If you are running with a Mobile device you may need to update the kernel.

Comment: @JonSkeet : TLS is run before the request is sent.  No request is sent if TLS fails So if TLS passes than you will get an HTTP Response with a status error.  The hanging is indicating no response occurred.  Title says does not work with HTTPS which I assume that it does work with HTTP.

Comment: I am using .net 4.5.2 and running as ASP.NET website.

Comment: @jdweng: If TLS negotiation failed, I'd expect an error saying as much rather than the process just hanging. I still see no evidence that this is a TLS issue. (And as I've noted, the change you first suggested does not help; I was using .NET 5 for testing, so it wasn't an issue on that front.)

Comment: You are using a very old version of Net which doesn't support TLS 1.2.  TLS 1.0 and 1.1 are obsolete and have been disabled on most servers last June when Microsoft did a security push.  Seee : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls?force_isolation=true

Comment: @JonSkeet : This failure is TLS.  Especially since user now says he is using Net 4.5.2 which will not work.  See my last comment.

Comment: @JonSkeet - I updated to .NET 4.8.0 and tried but the same issue is occurring.

Comment: I tried to check the SSL deep analysis of the URL through toolhttps://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/index.html but on that it is also giving HTTP request failed. HTTP request to this server failed,

Comment: @jdweng: Except you've failed to take into account that I've reproduced it with .NET 5, and that your suggested change made no difference to that. I just failed to see how you can make the leap from "the code hangs" to "it's definitely a TLS failure".

Comment: That URL isn't even working for me in a browser now...

Comment: @JonSkeet : There are lots of ways to cause TLS to fail.You have no proof that you cased TLS to fail exactly same as OP.You cannot say that you caused exact same failure when Core 5.0 is using the Operating System to do TLS and Net 4.5.2 is using TLS. You cannot prove if you are using the same version of TLS (1.2 or 1.3) no can you prove that you are using the same encryption mode as OP. TLS the server sends a Certificate block with the names of the certificate to use and if your client doesn't have the certificate loaded you are failing due to the certificate. While OP Net 4.5.2 can't do TLS.